# ASP.NET MVC Authorization along with WCF Web Services

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What approach is recommended in a case where I will be using ASP.NET MVC for authorization, but I will also have a few web services (WCF) that will be hit by JQuery AJAX requests once the user has been authorized.

I understand authorization in ASP.NET and in MVC.  It's straightforward.  One thing that I don't completely grasp is how my JQuery Ajax requests will become part of that session with the WCF services.  In JQuery Ajax, do I need to manually attach a client side authentication token in the header of the request?  Assuming this will be the same token returned from ASP.NET in the response header once the user is authorized?

Any tips on helping me understand how this works?

Comment: You could have a look at [Asp.net-MVC4 WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) which is a replacement of sorts for WCF. You'll write services as part of your mvc project so if you use cookie authentication that it'll just work with whatever service you write.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I am hoping to find out how to do it with regular WCF services as I have seen it done in the past.

Comment: Are these services part of the MVC project?